Can I fix this encoding issue with a copy and pasted .p12 Certificate?
Wondering if there is a work around, whether it be from advanced settings in Gmail or another text editor or command line fix for a pretty stupid issue.
I hastily opened a .p12 Certificate in Notepad, copied the text contents of the file from Notepad into a new composed Gmail message and e-mailed it to myself in a crunch. Of course, the encoding removed the special characters contained in a .p12 Certificate and replaced them with blank spaced characters. Is there any way to convert those spaces back into the appropriate characters?
Example of the first lines of the p12 Cert from the text formatting of the Gmail e-mail:
0‚ £   0‚ _  *†H†÷
    ‚ P ‚ L0‚ H0‚
±  *†H†÷
    ‚
¢ ‚
ž0‚
š0‚
–  *†H†÷

   ‚ ~0‚ z0
*†H†÷
    0   ©"RR¹½»    Ð ‚ X—}† ÂL@½H ÅI+m¢‰\a"]—$õ“ r}CeæŽ‘hš s&X§C1¦¯o ´Ûwö43
¢ÏµÇ$¥ Ü"†Íà¼úï Ó  .M »µ Œ ì ¡ÿõ¬~¶5| 6Š~ ·    yhÁÔné¡Zº#ð« aÞÜñ
=c2Úì,j à yBí Õà*hãþ þi S^ß‚{ ‘åãð Wg hø%‰É yš¬)Éðh—æX6bÉéA<¡´“G¼Ú=Œð@zÓ¯
2ö¨œ œ  ÇŸñ'^`G{h
–ò=¡ äåž õ_1o›X^1×# á„Wå=òŠ4r"Mj íüf´»Ì0úÁ\À«q¾3ìù€p×¯£tè3ÃÑ
Á¬ÛÒKßvÌ d‹ãxG r”¦–!è2 £ pë…Vrªæ y^uÔIò¹½·±Å\½è+2lc‹
õ/·Ý¬  ÷õ2¾ÆOEî8‡I Ùf>4 j,e P”Vì›/) å [p yP5’‰‚=Õ³¼n  ç2
‰WX •å n¬ÀúãºàÌ D§ý± dï© "JÐßa ¤ {KÃ  ¿ ˜Ýä¤Ô MƒÞÐPI
]  ó*¸eã
öI`8hKC†Ê«ïr'ò–Y]³  f &OÔeìuÿ}4 Ÿáv>ç·£ÙO vþ ) »
åôfnB² ¯x3"î¦A ™Ïè€>Å‡†ô  5 dQ%Î¦ëÌyí~ ÙC(¿=p‘†Á ( @`!FJ¥ ñíï
}r¸T°WÝ5†{PØ>Jp×Ät´ {iñ‡íN‰‡kcx/c†˜r¬ª–ÉjcêßA“(Îò?6õ9ø%ì©}«üD¤

The spaces naturally now signify the neutered special chars that are characteristic of the encoding of the original .p12 formatting as it appeared in the text editor, representing the black blocked abbreviation characters in Notepad++ ... i.e. SSA (), BPH (), HTJ (), SOS (), etc.
Below is a segmented example of the exact kind of formatting I desire to return the text to:
0 £ 0 _ *H÷
 P  L0 H0
± *H÷

¢ 
0
0
 *H÷

 ~0 z0
*H÷
0 ©"RR¹½» Р X} @½H ŉ+m¢\a"]$õ r}Ce控h s&X§C1¦¯o ´۷ö43
¢ϵǤ¥ ܢ͠¼ú .M »µ  젡ÿõ~~¶5| 6~ · yhÁԮ顚º#ޜ2ڬ,j ࠹Bન㾠‏i S^߂{ '声 Wg hّ%ɠy)ɰh昶bɩA<،´G¼ڽퟃ¯
2ِ¨  ǟG{h
䥞 ُ_1oX^1ף ᄗ彲4r"Mj ´»ْ̰ء\ہ«q¾3칀pׯ£t賃эء¬ےK߶̠d㸇 r¦!負£ p녖rھ根^uԉ±Ŝ½諲lc

...etc
If there is a way to identify and seek and replace the various blank chars, I'm open to suggestions. Thank you for enduring my ignorance. Looking forward to suggestions besides exporting .eml files, opening in various word processors, etc. Surely there is a way to convert it back into the appropriate character spaces? When I select the spaced out characters one by one, I am able to find different numbers of instances of each which leads me to believe there is still a placeholder for the original char identifiers rather than a blanket washing with simple spaces?
A fun debacle for 12:38 AM, I'm sure. ;) Thanks in advanced, someone(s) smarter!

Those weren't characters in the first place, just Notepad++'s attempt to represent the data as such. PKCS#12 files are not text (not even by the slightest amount), so even the idea of "special chars" or "text editor" does not make any sense with them.

Is there any way to convert those spaces back into the appropriate characters?

No, there isn't. Conversion can retain or lose information, but cannot recover information that has already been destroyed.
With just a few bytes corrupted it might be feasible to guess at their original values (possibly with referencing the PKCS#12 specification to understand what values make sense), and the file might have survived a copy/paste through Notepad++ alone (with only CR and LF needing to be guessed as to what their original values were), but after the "text" has gone through a web browser and the email system and the browser again, the chances of it still being repairable are exceedingly slim.

Looking forward to suggestions besides exporting .eml files, opening in various word processors, etc

There is no point in doing anything with the email message – it already contains garbage from the moment it was drafted (i.e. pasted into the browser's text-input), and no amount of exporting it will make it any better.
My only suggestion is to delete the message, then find the original file and send it again as an attachment. (Which would've been faster to do at first than opening it in NP++ given that you can drag & drop files into Gmail's compose window these days.)
